# error: no such partition. Grub rescue

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub

I deleted my Linux (Ubuntu) partition from Windows and I forgot to repair the MBR. I don't have my windows boot CD with me nor a CD drive. Is there any small utility that can be easily downloaded (I know about hiren CD but it's about 500 MB and I don't need that whole stuff) and which can be used from an USB drive? If yes, please explain the steps to perform. Thank you

**UPDATED**:
Small Linux live CDs are OK since I can boot them from an USB drive using [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com)

Comment: So, is your windows partition working fine?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [this software](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button) to make a USB boot disk of either knoppix and follow the instructions [here](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/11/how-to-repair-corrupt-mbr-and-boot.html) to repair.

Comment: sir i have already said that i need a small software which will do as much as i need, not more than that. Knoppix is approximately 3.7 GB and  I am not going to download that.

Comment: Then google lightweight linux distros. You can probably find many under 500 MB. It will be much easier for you to find a linux distro that does what you want (and will be around when you want something else) than to find a piece of software that does exactly what you want.

Comment: i am trying with slitaz live cd.. but not working

Answer (score 0):

It can be a real pain to boot from a USB key.  I would suggest getting a really cheap external CD-ROM drive and making the CD somewhere else for your computer.  I know that Knoppix is a really good system to retrieve files, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to completely start my windows PC by installing these boot drivers or whatever needed

Answer (score 0):

Without any information about your partition order, the easiest solution is probably to use Super Grub Disk (not Super Grub Disk 2): http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrubdiskdownload/ - Available as CD, pendrive or floppy image. Usage should be self explanatory but if you need some hint, see http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/UninstallGRUB

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see the grub prompt.

Grub can help you boot into your windows 7/xp environment and from there you can use various tools and utilites to fix MBR. But let me help you cover how are you going to boot into windows system from Grub. Once on the grub prompt.

type the following.

```
rootnoverify(hd0,0) 
makeactive
chainloader +1            
boot
```

You need to recollect if on partition the windows installed on your first partition, hence change the number according, the below naming convention can help you identify your partition

```
Grub designation  Meaning Usual designation
(hd0) First hard disk /dev/sda (or /dev/hda)
(hd1) Second hard disk /dev/sdb (or /dev/hdb)
(hd0,0) First hard disk, first partition /dev/sda1 (or /dev/hda1)
(hd1,0) Second hard drive, first partition /dev/sdb1 (or /dev/hdb1)
(hd1,1) Second hard drive, second partition /dev/sdb2 (or /dev/hdb2)
```

Now after this you would be able to boot to the windows system, from there onwards, you can eaisly fix your mbr using the tools from internet. this post can [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326532/how-to-fix-the-mbr-for-windows-7).