# Grub loading, please wait. . . Error 22

Tags: boot, grub, multi-boot, bootloader

Yesterday I got a problem which I posted [here](https://superuser.com/q/433569/138559). Trying to solve it, I installed slitaz live CD to desktop. After that I tried to use boot other live CD's (Ubuntu, Tiny core) but they didn't boot. So I deleted the the slitaz partition through gparted(or something like that) and restarted. After that I am seeing this error message:`

```
GRUB Loading stage 1.5.
Starting cmain() ...

GRUB loading, please wait...
Error 22`
```

**UPDATE:**
I have tried Backtrack live CD to live boot laptop but that doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Boot Backtrack or ubuntu live CD. Open terminal and run command "update grub" as root and then restart your laptop.